# JS code in functional presentation component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Still getting to grips with React and ES6. I have the following functional presentation component which works fine:

```
const Jobs = (props) => (
  <section id="jobs">
    <div>
      {
        props.jobs.map(job =>
          <div className="job" key={job.slug}>
            <p><strong>{job.title} at <Link to={"/jobs/" + job.slug}>{job.company}</Link></strong></p>
            <p>{job.intro}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  </section>
)
```

However, when I try to add some extra JS between the brackets as shown below I get errors about unexpected token.

```
const Jobs = (props) => (
  <section id="jobs">
    <div>
      {
        console.log("THIS DOESN'T WORK")
        props.jobs.map(job =>
          <div className="job" key={job.slug}>
            <p><strong>{job.title} at <Link to={"/jobs/" + job.slug}>{job.company}</Link></strong></p>
            <p>{job.intro}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  </section>
)
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with what [babel is transforming the code into](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/#example-react).

```
return <div>{myValue}</div>;
```

Becomes

```
return React.createElement("div", null, myValue);
```

So having a random `console.log` in the middle of that, such as

```
return <div>{
  console.log(myValue);
  myValue
}</div>;
```

Would become

```
return React.createElement("div", null, console.log(myvalue); myValue);
```

Obviously that is no longer valid javascript.  Because of this, the only thing that is valid inside a JSX transformation is an expression that evaluates to a single value.

---

Reading some of the comments on other answers, I see you are actually wanting to do conditional logic inside your JSX.

For this, you have a few options at your disposal.

**1. Extract a variable**

```
let conditionalValue = "Loading";

if (condition)
  conditionalValue = myValue;

return <div>{conditionalValue}</div>;
```

**2. Extract a method**

```
return <div>{renderValue()}</div>

...

renderValue() {
  if (condition)
    return myValue;

  return "Loading"
}
```

**3. Use a ternary**

```
return <div>{condition ? myValue : "Loading"}</div>;
```

**4. Exploit boolean evaluation**

If you want to show a fallback for something

```
return <div>{myValue || "Loading"}</div>;
```

If you want to only show something based on a condition

```
return <div>{condition && myValue}</div>;
```

---

**NOTE:** all of the above examples are just as valid if you replace `myValue` with another component, e.g. `<p>Hello World</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

According to React JSX docs:

> You can embed any JavaScript expression in JSX by wrapping it in curly
>   braces

and in JS the expression is:

> An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value.

So you can't put two or more expressions in single curly braces (`console.log` is one expression and maping over jobs is second expression). [@Michael Peyper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6902543/michael-peyper) has already thoroughly explained in his answer why this results in errors.

If you want to use `console.log` in your example you can just move it to separate bracecs:

```
const Jobs = (props) => (
  <section id="jobs">
    <div> 
      { console.log("THIS DOESN'T WORK") }
      {
        props.jobs.map(job =>
          <div className="job" key={job.slug}>
            <p><strong>{job.title} at <Link to={"/jobs/" + job.slug}>{job.company}</Link></strong></p>
            <p>{job.intro}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  </section>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @thinhvo said you cannot do logic inside return statement. Although looking into your needs, A simple work around could be like this.

```
const Jobs = (props) => {
  let conditionalComp = null;
  if(/*some condition*/ ) {
    conditionalComp = props.jobs.map(job =>
        <div className="job" key={job.slug}>
          <p><strong>{job.title} at <Link to={"/jobs/" + job.slug}>{job.company}</Link></strong></p>
          <p>{job.intro}</p>
        </div>
      );
  }
  return (
    <section id="jobs">
      <div>
        {conditionalComp}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to keep the return clean. try to make maps and processing outside the render return.

```
const Jobs = (props) => {
    console.log("THIS DOESN'T WORK")
    const jobs = props.jobs.map(job =>
        <div className="job" key={job.slug}>
            <p><strong>{job.title} at <Link to={"/jobs/" + job.slug}>{job.company}</Link></strong></p>
            <p>{job.intro}</p>
        </div>
    )
    return (
        <section id="jobs">
            <div>
                {jobs}
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't do that by the current way, the first `console.log("THIS DOESN'T WORK")` is still inside the JSX, and the JSX will only understand react's elements or DOM.

Therefore, if you want to do extra JS, please do inside the `map` function (before returning value):

```
<div>
  {
    props.jobs.map((job) => {
      console.log("something here");
      return (
        <div className="job" key={job.slug}>
          <p><strong>{job.title} at <Link to={"/jobs/" + job.slug}>{job.company}</Link></strong></p>
          <p>{job.intro}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    )
  }
</div>
```

=====

Did you take notice of me adding `()` and `{}` ? This is, in fact, the way we write in ES6, using `=>` for lexical binding the function to the current react-component.

Your previous code `props.jobs.map( job => <div> </div> )` is just a fast way to return some JSX element (which is the `div`)

=====

**ADDED VERSION**: to do the logic (conditional) for the mapping:

```
const Jobs = (props) => {
  let returned_jsx = (<div>No Job!</div>);
  if (props.jobs.length) { // or whatever condition you need!
    returned_jsx = (
      <section id="jobs">
        <div>
          {
            props.jobs.map(job =>
              <div className="job" key={job.slug}>
                <p><strong>{job.title} at <Link to={"/jobs/" + job.slug}>{job.company}</Link></strong></p>
                <p>{job.intro}</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
  return returned_jsx;
}
```

The above code is just an example on how to do logic to return different things in JSX. If you still have errors, please post here and we will discuss further, thanks

Comment: Though not specified in the question I would like to conditionally perform the mapping. Otherwise I would like to return `<h1>Loading</h1>` - could you update your answer as this would be a great help?

Comment: Ok, I partially understand your need. Actually you cannot do logic (like conditional) inside the JSX. However, you can do a work-around way, please see my edited version, I will add an example for you after 5-10 minutes. Thanks

Comment: Have just added the code for conditional, that will, in my opinion, give you more "freedom" to customize results

Comment: Have you made it work ^^? If yes, please consider an up-vote or accept for my answer, since it is one of the soonest, and also one of the most detailed answers, I think! Besides, I added code based on your need, just to practical and solve your real problem! Thanks